# Window.location intermittently fails to load in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reload

I have an aspx page with JS calling window.location.reload(true) to force refresh a page when a function is called.

This appears to work a few times, with the page reloading as expected, but gets to a scenario where the function is called (i.e. alert in the function is visible) but the reload does not occur. I've also tried setting window.location with the same outcome - it works 2 or 3 times then fails.

This does not occur in Firefox (16), but is happening in different versions of IE (7 & 9)

Using Fiddler to monitor the browser traffic, all is as expected when the reload is working, but there is no traffic reported when the reload stops, suggesting the browser is not sending the request to the server? The IE window does go blank with the loading spinner spinning, but eventually IE displays the error page:

> ```
> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage 
>
> Most likely causes:
> You are not connected to the Internet. 
> The website is encountering problems. 
> There might be a typing error in the address.
> ```

This appears to lock the browser. Trying to hit another website results in the same output in Fiddler (nothing). Opening a new IE window means I am able to hit the site with no problems.

This was initially causing a problem updating UpdatePanels via __doPostBack so this JS reload of the page was seen as a quick workaround, but this does not seem to be the case.

I would tend to think this is server related, but I have been unable to replicate the issue in Firefox. This does however unfortunately have to work in IE.

Any ideas much appreciated!

JS snippet below (though this is pretty simple stuff)

```
function ReloadWindow() {
    alert(window.location); // Can see this alert, even when page fails to reload

    window.location.reload(true);

}
```

Comment: Make sure the URL doesn't contain any hash/anchor. e.g.: no `#abc` at the end of URL. If it does, remove the hash part. If you're not expecting any hash part in the URL for any of your pages, this is usually due to JavaScript error somewhere in your JavaScript code.